# How to reference single instance of RestClient?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, restsharp

Using the latest version of `RestSharp` and the documentation states

> Do not instantiate RestClient for each HTTP call. RestSharp creates a
> new instance of HttpClient internally, and you will get lots of
> hanging connections, and eventually exhaust the connection pool.

Therefore i already have a Base class which cant be changed that is used by all my MVC Controllers.

I thought i could create my own class but this would mean everytime a page makes a request it would create another instance as i would need to instantiate a new instance.

How could i instantiate a single `RestClient` so if i have 10 pages making a call it utilises the one instance as per the documentation?

Any examples would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Service

I think the best solution could be to have a service that your controllers use to make the rest call and that service will have a single static `RestClient`.

## No DI option, no service option

You could insert a class between the base class and your controllers

```
class WithRestClient: Base 
{
protected static RestClient = new RestClient  ... (or in the constructor)
}

class Ctrl1: WithRestClient { ...
class Ctrl2: WithRestClient { ...
```

## With DI

You could setup a singleton `RestClient` in `Startup` and have that injected into your Controllers as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Thanks - Im trying the option With DI to start with. Is there a way for me to monitor the Connection pool to see what the count is to ensure it is 1 instance?

Comment: You can `Object.ReferenceEquals` to check when debugging....